# Show hide <tr> not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Can someone help me:

I try to hide and show a row with two cells. The content is in cell two.
It is working fine in IE, but in FF and Chrome it seems like all the content trys to fit in the Space of the first cell. Here is my code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50"></td>
    <td width="650">
      <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r1" value="" class="small" onClick="Hide('div_test', this);">
      <label for="r1">Skjul</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" id="r2" name="r1" value="" class="small" onClick="Reveal('div_test', this);">
      <label for="r2">Vis</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="div_test" style="display:none;">
    <td width="50"></td>
    <td width="650">Dette er også en test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the script:

```
function Reveal (it, box) 
{ 
    var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
    document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
}


function Hide (it, box) 
{ 
    var vis = (box.checked) ? "none" : "none"; 
    document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are u loading the script before or after the definition of the table?

Comment: Obviously after because the function can only be called when their input tag is loaded. @Ipad

Comment: the script before the table

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `display` to `table-row` not block because it's a table row!

http://jsfiddle.net/xsrdeuw4/

```
function Reveal (it, box) 
{ 
    var vis = (box.checked) ? "table-row" : "none"; 
    document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
}
```

Comment: @SanneFaurholt you should consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/190623) if you find that it solved your problem.