# click event does not work with firefox

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have a function which works very well with safari und chrome , but not with firefox. By clicking the button , it appears three inputfields with the name hid. So user can fill in. And clicking again, the fields disappears.
Firefox Problem: When i click, nothings happens. What is wrong with the function?
thanks

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

{literal}
$( "#muendbtn" ).click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $( "tr[name=hid]" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
        $( "tr[name=hid]" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    } else {
        $( "tr[name=hid]" ).fadeOut();
    }
});
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: share the html also

Comment: What on earth is `{literal} … {/literal}`? It's not Javascript…

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788360/show-hide-tr-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox

Answer (score 0):

try to put event as a parameter.. Like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

{literal}
$( "#muendbtn" ).click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $( "tr[name=hid]" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
        $( "tr[name=hid]" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    } else {
        $( "tr[name=hid]" ).fadeOut();
    }
});
{/literal}
</script>
```